# In Webstorm node express app: router.post() shows error: unresolved function or method post()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm

When I run the localhost:3000/users/yu , I get a 404 not found. Why is the post() coming up as undefined? when I run a POST from my iOS app I get a "undefined token" error. I'm running node v5.7.0 and express v4.13.4 Project was generated using [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to create Webstorm project.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

        var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();


    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.send("yoma");
    });

    router.post('/yu', function(req, res) {
      var test = req.body;
      //parse test
    });
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Are you asking about a `404 error` or are you asking about a `unresolved function or method` warning in Webstorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you navigate your browser to `localhost:3000/users/yu` it makes `GET` http query, but in your router you have only `POST` handler for `'/yu'`

```
router.post('/yu', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
});
```

Add GET handler for `'/yu'` like this for example

```
router.get('/yu', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
});
```

After that you should not get a 404 error when navigate to `localhost:3000/users/yu`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't ask the proper question. For some reason the POST method is coming up as undefined in my user.js (first snippet shown above). Is there an alternative, or is my work space not set up correctly?

Comment: I think it's not about IDE. What you mean "the POST method is coming up as undefined" ? `var myVar = router.post(...)` is `undefined`?

Comment: Yea it was coming up as undefined, but it turns out I was incorrectly setting up the HTTPBody from my iOS client. As it turns out, the POST method being undefined in Webstorm doesn't matter at all. I was tripped up by that because Webstorm recognized the router.post(...), and then later didn't. Thanks!